# Android Google Map: Calculate radius to be drawn depend on meters and zoom level of map

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I would like to known if there is a way to calculate radius to be drawn on Google Map.
Now I have a GoogleMap with ViewOverlay over it for inverting the selection. So I want to know what is actual radius (which to be drawn) equal to.

`radiusToByDrawnOnViewOverlay = radiusFromSeekBar * currentGoogleMapZoom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here: https://gist.github.com/amay077/6879638. Actually this is method which was deprecated in GoogleMap.